# Open Mic issue for DialogFlow app

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

My submission of Dialogflow app got denied due to open mic issue.

> ERROR : "During our testing, we found that your app would sometimes *leave the mic open for the user without any prompt*. Make sure that your app always says something before leaving the mic open for the user, so that the user knows what they can say. This is particularly important when your app is first triggered.

Current implementation :
User asks something and app replies back with static text and a static basic card content. The Google Assistant bot reads out the text and then mic open momentarily for user voice input.

NOTE THAT :

- **THERE IS NO FULFILLMENT REQUEST.**
- **I DO NOT WANT TO END CONVERSATION HERE**
- **ALL ARE STATIC RESPONSES**

HOW DO I SOLVE THIS ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a sample interaction with a couple back and forth exchanges between user and "bot" in your question, so we can see how ideally you want the interaction to proceed.  Prisoner is probably right, you just need to tack on a "say the next one or cancel" to keep the flow moving.

Answer (score 2):

The important part in the rejection is that you left the mic open *without any prompt*.

This usually means that your action has said something like "The answer is four" without giving any idea what the user should do now, or that it is the user's turn to speak.

A reply such as "The answer is four. What would you like to do now?" should meet the requirements. The point is to prompt the user to be aware the conversation isn't over.