# Google Action is not getting approved

Tags: actions-on-google

During our testing, we found that your app would sometimes leave the mic open for the user without any prompt. Make sure that your app always says something before leaving the mic open for the user, so that the user knows what they can say. This is particularly important when your app is first triggered.

Comment: This question is just like another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098109/open-mic-issue-for-dialogflow-app

Comment: This is something different

Comment: What's wrong with what they have said? You need to make sure you close the session after you have completed the user's task.

Answer (score 0):

The important part in the rejection is that you left the mic open without any prompt.

This usually means that your action has said something like "The answer is four" without giving any idea what the user should do now, or that it is the user's turn to speak.

A reply such as "The answer is four. What would you like to do now?" should meet the requirements. The point is to prompt the user to be aware the conversation isn't over.

If you feel you're doing this, perhaps you can update the question to explain what your Action is doing and why you feel it is meeting the design requirements.