# Is there a way to force the speaker and microphone to stay in in a Dlaolgflow chatbot?

Tags: html, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I've created a chatbot on my website using Dialogflow ES. I'm integrating it on my website using Dialogflow Web via the below code:

```
    <iframe
        allow="microphone;"
        width="350"
        height="430"
        src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/792f14ec-88a3-4b0b-ba65-5dab3573fdae">
    </iframe>
```

The bot works wonderfully, except that when I want to carry on a conversation, I have to click the microphone to speak every single time I utter a sentence and I have to click the speaker icon next to the bot's output when I want to hear it speak.

Is there any way I can just enable the microphone and speaker for the entire session?

Comment: I think it is because dialogflow has lots of background services related to that button and it is not something you can do with your html code.

Comment: Thanks for responding,  JackSparrow . I was hoping that I could incorporates some JavaScript or other scripting language?

Comment: There is sadly no way other than janky workarounds(which are apparently not welcome, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098109/open-mic-issue-for-dialogflow-app ), I think best way is to contact them directly.